# Is it a good practice to use classes to store and list variables/methods in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I've started to recently utilise classes in programming, specifically C++ in this case, and I am trying to understand ideal ways to use them practically. Ideally I want to get in the habit of practising writing them how the industry would expect, if such a standard does exist. I understand you may use classes to hold specific information useful to an object, such as a car class. But what about about classes such as 'Formulas()' which would only store methods the rest of your program can utilise, or a variable only class to hold constants, global variables, or just generally anything you want other programs to access.

```
int main()
{
    //Just used minimally to start the program
}


class Car()
{
    //Variables of a car: Model, year etc
    //Methods of a car: Such as drive(), parkUp(); refuel(); 
}

//Below here is class formalities I'm unsure about, are they okay to use this way
class Formulas()
{
    //holds a bunch of a formulas/methods almost all the classes can utilize
    //Examples below
    void ErrorCheck()
    {
        //checks input errors
    }
    void ColourChange()
    {
        //changes font colour
    }
    void Clear()
    {
        //clears screen
    }
}

//A class to hold variables for the rest of the program
class VariableList()
{
    //store CONST_VARIABLES here

    //store global_variables here

    //other variables
}
```

To summarise, is this a fair way to use classes, unpractical, awful etc.

Any type of insight on this would be greatly appreciated. I tried looking into this before posting here, but couldn't quite find the source or interpret the information to get the answer I was looking for. Thank you for reading this far, and if there's anything I can add please let me know.

Comment: Depending on whom you ask Data classes are either a requirement or an anti-pattern.

For more on why they are an anti-pattern read [this](https://refactoring.guru/smells/data-class).

IMO structs in C++ serve the purpose complex data objects. Where logically related info gets lumped together.

Classes are structs+ functions that operate on the data. (Of course there are more diferences like the default scope etc, but I'm talking from a design perspective)

Comment: @Srini: True, but the question is not about data classes. It is abour using classes to group functions.

Comment: @FrankPuffer I may have misinterpreted the question. you are right :)

Answer (score 7):

Classes normally only make sense to encapsulate data and to group it with functions that operate on this data. If you only want to group a number of related functions that do not operate on the same data, a namespace instead of a class would be sufficient.

In your case it could llook like this:

```
namespace formulas
{
    void ErrorCheck()
    {
        //checks input errors
    }
    void ColourChange()
    {
        //changes font colour
    }
    void Clear()
    {
        //clears screen
    }
}
```

Then you can call the functions as:

```
formulas::ErrorCheck();
```

By the way, your functions don't really seem to be related, but I guess this is not the point.

Comment: This! Classes encapsulate the data and the functions that manipulate that particular data. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Thank you! I've only been doing C++ itself a week so wasn't aware you could use namespaces in this way, which is probably awful of me. Genuinely thank you for pointing me in the right direction Frank! :)

Edit: And regarding the class for holding variables, i'm guessing that's a no go too? Would it be better just to store amongst other classes/main?

Comment: @ChrisRafferty: One week? I had been programming C++ for at least a year before using namespaces this way :).

Comment: @ChrisRafferty general rule of thumb that extends the above: [if a function doesn't make use of a class's `private` data it probably shouldn't be a class member](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c4-make-a-function-a-member-only-if-it-needs-direct-access-to-the-representation-of-a-class) A read-through of the [Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) is time well spent, but remember that they're guidelines, not rules.